# UTC time in a given local time

Tags: .net

In .net how can I find out the UTC time given a known local time?  e.g. what's the UTC when it is 05:30 local time in Singapore?

I have an application which needs to show data from 07:00 'local time', from remote centres. For example, I might need to query data from London starting at 07:00, from a machine based in Singapore. London might be in either GMT or Daylight savings, in which case my query should be starting at either 06:00 or 07:00.

How could I go about this?

Comment: UTC is the same everywhere. Are you looking for `DateTime.UtcNow`?

Comment: I have rephrased the question - my fault

Comment: Rephrasing didn't help. UTC is the same everywhere. There is no "UTC time in a specific local time". Are you trying to convert a UTC time to Local time? Or are you trying to convert a local time to UTC ?

Answer (score 0):

Your application would convert all incoming times to a UTC time before processing. When you send a time back to a client, you send convert the time back to the clients local time.

Comment: Or it should use [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx), to avoid any timezone ambiguities

Answer (score 0):

- How can I find out the UTC time given a known local time?

Utc Time is the same everywhere you are.

- What's the UTC when it is 05:30 local time in Singapore?

You can use [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

Best practice is to convert everything to UTC time before you do your businesslogic. That way you always query on UTC time and the time zone of your customer does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

As a DateTime does not include timezone information, you can make one for the time in Singapore and use that in a DateTimeOffset which you can then use to get the UTC time (*and date*) corresponding to that:

```
Option Infer On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dtFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

        Dim tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Singapore Standard Time")
        Dim d = DateTime.UtcNow
        Dim singaporeTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(d, tzi)

        Console.WriteLine("It is " & singaporeTime.ToString(dtFormat) & " in Singapore.")

        Dim st = New DateTime(2015, 7, 9, 5, 30, 0) ' local time in Singapore '
        Dim sst As New DateTimeOffset(st, tzi.GetUtcOffset(st))

        Console.WriteLine("At " & st.ToString(dtFormat) & " in Singapore it is " & sst.ToUniversalTime.ToString(dtFormat) & " UTC.")

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Which right now outputs

> It is 2015-07-09 17:34:09 in Singapore.
>   At 2015-07-09 05:30:00 in Singapore it is 2015-07-08 21:30:00 UTC.